# Image module for photogaleries

Tags: 7, media

I wanted to download [Image](http://drupal.org/project/image) module, but I notice that it's not for Drupal 7. Is there some alternative I can use in Drupal 7?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Future of Image in Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/513096) reports the following text:

> Image module is being put into core, but not in its current incarnation. Drupal 7 has already made several major improvements that will make handling images (and files in general) much easier, eliminating a lot of the existing code from image.module.

> The Drupal 7 core plan is as follows:
>
> - Move ImageAPI into core to provide better support for toolkits such as ImageMagick (done).
> - Move ImageCache into core to provide thumbnailing abilities as part of image.module (in progress).
> - Move FileField into core as file.module.
> - Move ImageField into core as part of image.module.

This means that most of the functionality of those modules are already integrated in Drupal 7.
[ImageAPI](http://drupal.org/project/imageapi) still contains code that has not been merged with Drupal 7 code; you should install it if you need the ImageMagick toolkit it implements, or the unsharpen mask action.

As gallery modules, you can try:

- [Galleria](http://drupal.org/project/galleria)
- [Fast Gallery](http://drupal.org/project/fast_gallery)
- [Galerie](http://drupal.org/project/galerie)

Answer (score 1):

There are actually a lot of modules that have been ported to (or are initially written for) Drupal 7. A typical example is [Gallery Formatter](http://drupal.org/project/galleryformatter).

However, if I were you, I would read thoroughly through the following 2 links:

[Link 1](http://drupal.org/node/1029174)

[Link 2](http://drupal.org/node/1029174#comment-4323744)

since there are a lot of different ways to create a photo gallery in Drupal 7. You have to pick the way that is the more convenient for you (e.g. you may want a module that does just this, or you may want to stick to the "lego-logic" of drupal and create the gallery from a cck field).